# Linq left join and count - How To

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have the following Linq expression:

```
var employeeTypes = from t in DbContext.Set<SetupEmployeeType>().AsNoTracking()
                    join emp in DbContext.Set<Employee>().AsNoTracking() on t.EmployeeTypeId equals emp.EmployeeTypeId into employee
                    from subemp in employee.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where t.MasterEntity == masterEntity
                    select new Model.SetupEmployeeTypeModel()
                    {
                        EmployeeTypeId = t.EmployeeTypeId,
                        Description = t.Description,
                        AllowProbation = t.AllowProbation,
                        IsActive = t.IsActive,
                        TotalEmployee = (subemp == null ? 0 : subemp.Count) 

                    };
```

I need to set `TotalEmployee` property of my custom model.

So if there is no `EmployeeTypeId` associated to any Employee then `TotalEmployee` should be **0**, else should be the **Count of Employees**.

Any clue how to do this?

Comment: A GroupBy may be appropriate.

Comment: Any clue on how to do that GroupBy with left join?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i may not wrong then consider using a subquery, like so -

```
var q = from empType in DbContext.Set<SetupEmployeeType>().AsNoTracking()
        let empCount =
        (
          from emp in DbContext.Set<Employee>().AsNoTracking()
          where empType.EmployeeTypeId == emp.EmployeeTypeId
          select emp
        ).Count()
        select new Model.SetupEmployeeTypeModel()
        {
            EmployeeTypeId = empType.EmployeeTypeId,
            Description = empType.Description,
            AllowProbation = empType.AllowProbation,
            IsActive = empType.IsActive,
            TotalEmployee = empCount
        };
```

### Using Group by.

```
var q = from empType in DbContext.Set<SetupEmployeeType>().AsNoTracking()
        join empCnt in 
            (
                from emp in DbContext.Set<Employee>().AsNoTracking()
                group emp by emp.EmployeeTypeId into grp
                select new { EmployeeTypeId = grp.Key, TotalEmp = grp.Count()}
            ) on empType.EmployeeTypeId equals empCnt.EmployeeTypeId into employees
        from subemp in employees.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where t.MasterEntity == masterEntity
        select new Model.SetupEmployeeTypeModel()
        {
            EmployeeTypeId = empType.EmployeeTypeId,
            Description = empType.Description,
            AllowProbation = empType.AllowProbation,
            IsActive = empType.IsActive,
            TotalEmployee = subemp.TotalEmp
        };
```

Comment: I just publish my solution... seems your code do the same but different way using the "let". thats nice

Comment: @VAAA:- Yes you have done it using group by and i have used subquery. Well frankly speaking first i have done it using group by but then i realized that you only want the count then why not subquery... :). see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following solution:

```
 var employeeTypes = from t in DbContext.Set<SetupEmployeeType>().AsNoTracking()
                                join empg in
                                    (
                                        from emp in DbContext.Set<Employee>().AsNoTracking()
                                        group emp by emp.EmployeeTypeId into g
                                        select new { EmployeeTypeId = g.Key, Total = g.Count() }
                                    ) on t.EmployeeTypeId equals empg.EmployeeTypeId into employee
                                from subemp in employee.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                where t.MasterEntity == masterEntity

                                select new Model.SetupEmployeeTypeModel()
                                {
                                    EmployeeTypeId = t.EmployeeTypeId,
                                    Description = t.Description,
                                    AllowProbation = t.AllowProbation,
                                    IsActive = t.IsActive,
                                    TotalEmployee = subemp.Total 

                                };
```